What's this movie where a girl turns into an old hag after having sex?
Sadly, all I remember is one scene: 

There's a guy in a room inside an old mansion.
He meets a young beauty and has sex with her.
When he wakes up there's a mummy/old hag lying beside him.

I think he's in the mansion with a group of people. 
The genre is maybe comedy/horror and made in the 1980s-90s.
Hopefully, someone can shed some light on this matter.

Another user, @AndrewThompson, suggested some good edits to your post. I added my two bits to that, plus a few tags. And I think it works :-) Always nice to keep questions concise and easy to read.

@rumandwrite  Your edit is excellent.  The question is very clear now. :)

I know this is not what you're looking for (hence a comment instead of an A), but I think it's worth mentioning that Kubrick's The Shining has a rather similar scene. (Go to youtube and look for the shining bathroom scene.)

Also unlikely what you are searching, but maybe relevant: The British comedy/mystery show “Misfits“ has an episode where a young guy sleeps with a girl, which during sex turns out to be an old woman.


High Spirits (1988)
Edited from the LA Times, here's a synopsis:

An impoverished Lord, Peter Plunkett desperately tries to save his bankrupt patrimony by converting his castle into a ghostly theme
  park with banshees on pulleys and servants under sheets.

Like you said, there were others at the castle:

Sharon, married to a charming nebbish Jack, is one of the customers on
  the unveiling of Plunkett's haunts. The others include a yowling
  parapsychologist, his flaky wife and a kitten-voiced sexpot, her eye
  on a hapless Catholic novitiate.

Now the real fun begins:

The turn of the screwball here is that the castle is actually
  haunted by a troubled 200-years-dead couple, trapped in a nightly
  re-enactment of their murderous nuptials.

Jack meets and falls in love with one of the "real" ghosts, Mary. Here she is in "youthful" times:

After they spend the night together:

Read more about it here, here and here. Watch the movie here to confirm.
~ Screenshots taken from Wonder and Risk and TV Movie
